# Layout issue with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a functioning autocomplete but when the results are returned I will see a label created in my UI telling me the number of results I have and it will shift the control to the right, totally messing up the look of the page.  I am not doing any special styling of this autocomplete, it is just a simple .

I like the functionality of having the label display the number of results but I would prefer that it appear above the  control.

How can this be accomplished?

[image: Before Auto Complete is triggered]

[image: After Auto Complete is triggered]

[image: The highlighted line is the span that is created by jQuery's autocomplete]

Comment: It will be good if you can post  a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Too much code I think to post in Fiddle.  Just wondering if someone knows if this is a simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the input to display:block so that the span appears above it when it's added to the DOM. Assuming the input is added by the plugin:

```
$(function() {
   $("#autocompleteRequestors").css("display","block");
})
```

Alternatively, if you're adding the input through markup just set `style='display: block'` :)

Comment: that's FANTASTIC!  Just what I wanted.  Thank you SO much! :-)